# Updating CSS stylesheet without recompiling the JavaFX 2 project

Tags: css, javafx-2

Here [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm)
I found that "Skinning your UI with JavaFX CSS enables you to change the UI shown in Figure 1 to the UI shown in Figure 2 just by changing the style sheet used.", but after compiling my project I cannot find any css files in dist folder.

So my question: is it possible to change style without recompiling app and how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

There are next options:

1. Put css files on web server and use links like:

   ```
   scene.getStylesheets().add("http://myhost.com/style.css");
   ```

   or

   ```
   scene.getStylesheets().add("file:///E:/style.css");
   ```
2. Explain to designers how to update css files using any archive manager or jar utility from jdk:

   ```
   jar uf FXApp.jar style.css
   ```

Comment: Still not working. Then i opened jar file and found that css files hiding there, so i now thinking how to make it easy for my designers to stylish apps

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood you. Updated my answer.